# universal security in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have created web site with mvc. i have created security part of this web site. users can register on it. and information about user will stay on aspnet_users and aspnet_membership(roles in aspnet_roles). i looked at this tables and saw that all information are belong to a application(to my current web site). but i want to make so that when i will create a new web site all users which has registered on first site can logon without registration. how i can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could configure both sites to point to the same SQL database for authentication and authorization. For this you will need a separate instance of SQL server accessible from both sites.